# Receiving unicode string in c

Tags: c, unicode

I want to write a simple c program that receives a unicode string. However, even though I compile in UNICODE, it seems like my wscanf function looks at the string as an ANSI string. 
My code goes like that:

```
wchar_t name[25];
wscanf(L"%s",name);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you on Windows using UTF-16 or some other system and using UTF-32?

Comment: Well, Hawkings gave a good answer. Still, you might want to read [utf8everywhere.org](http://utf8everywhere.org). Consider if using anything but UTF-8 internally really makes sense. (Externally anything but UTF-8 is just plain a bad ides outside some exotic cases (even there it is not done)). Also, beware buffer overflow.

Comment: @user3497668 What did you enter?  What was printed or in the debugger?

Comment: "ANSI string"? What's that? Perhaps you meant ASCII or Windows-1252 or something... ANSI is the American National Standards Institute...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the format specifier `%ls` (`%lc` for a single char).

```
wchar_t name[25];
wscanf(L"%ls",name);
```

Comment: I tried that, but still, it doesn't recognize my string as an UNICODE string. When I debug and look upon the locals, it seems like that all have an ascii value (and you can't see any letter).

Comment: One more intersting thing is that when I hardcode name with a unicode value, it does show up in the locals. Why does it happen?